# reverse vs reverse_lazy? Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Tengo una duda y es cual es mejor `reverse` o `reverse_lazy`?, vi por ahi que era mejor `reverse_lazy` y que es mejor utilizar `reverse_lazy` en todo, porque es una función que se ejecuta en tiempo de ejecución y no debe validarse durante la carga de Django. y que de `reverse` cabe la posibilidad de que no se valide en ejecución, algo asi....

Me refiero que por ejemplo en ves de utilizar en el método`get_success_url`, `reverse` pues es mejor utilizar `reverse_lazy` ya que es mejor. (Como lo explique anteriormente.)

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('pages:pages')
```

Prácticamente que `reverse_lazy` remplace casi totalmente a `reverse`(bueno no tan exagerado) Bueno espero hacerme entender.

Pero aun no logro entender muy bien cual es la diferencia entre `reverse` y `reverse_lazy` y cual es mejor. También ¿Como funcionan exactamente cada una?

**De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como parte de la aplicación Django, en alguna parte debe existir un fichero que la documentación denomina "URLConf", pero que en tu caso tendrá el nombre que hayas decidido ponerle (normalmente se llamará `urls.py`  o similar, y puede haber varios de éstos, pero habrá uno "maestro" que importe el resto).

Este fichero contiene una variable `urlpatterns` que es una lista de mapeos entre urls y los métodos que deben ejecutarse para servir esas URLS. Por ejemplo, cosas como:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/<int:year>/', view=views.year_archive, name="archive"),
    # ...etc
]
```

Cuando Django haya leido ese archivo, sabrá que una petición a la ruta `articles/2019/` debe convertirse en una ejecución de `views.year_archive()`, pasándole como parámetro 2019. También asocia el nombre "archive" con esa vista.

Pues bien, cuando usas `reverse("archive", kwargs={"year": 2019})` estás pidiendo que Django te diga cuál sería la ruta que causaría la ejecución de la vista "archive" con parámetro `year=2019` (se trataría de la ruta `"/articles/2019/"`).

Si cuando ejecutas `reverse()` Django ya había leido tu `urls.py`, ya tendrá la información para responderte, pues ya conoce que el nombre "archive" ha sido asociado a la ruta `/articles/<int:year>/`.

Pero ya que en Python todo es dinámico, es posible que en el momento que ejecutas `reverse("archive", ...)` el fichero `urls.py` aún no haya sido cargado (aunque será cargado más adelante, depende del orden en que se hagan los `import`, los `include`, etc.). Entonces el intento de usar `reverse("archive", ...)` producirá un error ya que el nombre `"archive"` aún no está asociado a ninguna ruta.

Entonces es cuando `reverse_lazy()` puede ser útil. Cuando usas `reverse()` el resultado es una cadena (la URL inversa que querías), pero cuando usas `reverse_lazy()` el resultado es una función, que será llamada al final, una vez todos los ficheros de configuración se hayan cargado y la respuesta esté a punto de enviarse al cliente. Para entonces ya será conocido el nombre `"archive"` y la función `reverse_lazy()` podrá usar `reverse()` para generar su respuesta.

No tengo mucha experiencia con Django y no sabría decirte cuál de las dos "es mejor". Por lo que he leido parece que la gente en general usa `reverse()` y si se encuentra con un error, la cambia por `reverse_lazy()`. No tengo claro por qué no es mejor usar directamente `reverse_lazy()` en todas partes para ahorrarte problemas, salvo por el hecho de que esta última implica una llamada extra a otra función, lo que puede repercutir un poco en el rendimiento, pero considero que este efecto es despreciable. El caso es que aparentemente `reverse_lazy()` se usa muy poco, aunque no sabría decirte por qué.

Comment: El `urls.py` "maestro" se encuentra en el directorio del proyecto, el resto de archivos `urls.py` se encuentran en las distintas aplicaciones que tenga el proyecto. El `reverse_lazy` como bien has dicho, resulta útil cuando se necesite un `reverse` antes de que se haya cargado el archivo `urls.py`. Un caso podría ser cuando se deba proporcionar una `url` a un decorador, o cuando una vista basada en una clase tenga un atributo `url`. Dejo el enlace de la documentación por si no queda claro del todo. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/ref/urlresolvers/