# Crear usuarios usando del modelo de Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

No se porque pero no funciona, estoy intentando crear usuario pero solo redirecciona al **inicio** ni si quiera al login.

**Vista**

```py
class RegistroUsuario(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UsuarioForm
    template_name = "registro.html"
    success_url = 'login'
```

**Formulario**

```py
class UsuarioForm(UserCreationForm):
        class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = [
                        'first_name',
                        'last_name',
                        'email',
                        'username',
                        'password'
                ]
                labels = {
                        'first_name':'Nombres',
                        'last_name': 'Apellidos',
                        'email': 'Correo electronico',
                        'username': 'Nombre de usuario',
                        'password': 'Ingrese su contraseña'
                }
                widgets = {
                        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'required': True, 'placeholder': 'Ingrese su nombre'}),
                        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Ingrese su apellido'}),
                        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Ingrese su correo electronico'}),
                        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Ingrese su nombre de usuario'}),
                        'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Ingrese su contraseña'}),
                        'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','required': True, 'placeholder': 'Confirme su contraseña'}),
                }
```

**URL**

```py
path('registro', RegistroUsuario.as_view(), name='nuevoUs'),
```

**Modelo**

```py
class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```

Como dije estoy usando el modelo de **Django 3** entre mas documentación reviso mas me confundo sin mencionar los ejemplos, en los tutorías y demás.

**Template**

```html
<form method="post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="inputFirstName">Nombre</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="inputLastName">Apellido</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputLastName" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="inputEmailAddress">Correo electronico</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputEmailAddress" type="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingrese su correo electronico" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="inputUserName">Nombre de usuario</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputuserName" type="username" aria-describedby="usernamelHelp" placeholder="Ingrese su username" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="inputPassword">Clave</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="inputConfirmPassword">Confirme su clave</label>
                <input class="form-control py-4" id="inputConfirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'nuevoUs' %}">Crear una cuenta "nuevo"</a> -->
                <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Unete' %}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Estoy logeado a mi sitio con el super usuario (superuser) el resto de vistas funciona lo de cerrar sesión, recuperar clave por email **y** listar actividades (esta vista son los registros de ese usuario logeado). **Todas** estas vistas funcionan pero no puedo crear usuarios. Por ende tampoco puedo logear me.

```py
path('cuenta/login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name ='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu vista, una ves se cree el objeto te debe redirigir a la siguiente URL: `registro/login`, la cual no existe y debería dar un error 404.

> El atributo [`success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) debe ser la URL a la que se debe
> redirigir cuando el formulario se procesa correctamente.

Entonces debes utilizar la función [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy), que "genera" una URL en base al nombre de patrón de URL, existe la función [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) que seria algo similar a [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy), pero en este caso necesitas utilizar la función [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) ya que vas a "generar" la URL antes de cargar el URLConf de tu proyecto (para mas información sobre [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) y [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) te sugiero revisar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258616/reverse-vs-reverse-lazy-django))

Entonces el atributo [`success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.success_url) debería ser así:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

---

#### Actualización:

Acabo de caer en cuenta, de que el porque no se crea el usuario, y es por tu formulario HTML, pues los elementos `<input>` no tienen el atributo `name`, entonces, una solución es poner el atributo `name` a los `<input>` manualmente, pero lo mejor es que Django genere automáticamente los `<input>`.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.first_name.id_for_label }}">Nombre</label>
                {{ form.first_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.last_name.id_for_label }}">Apellido</label>
                {{ form.last_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">Correo electronico</label>
                {{ form.email }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Nombre de usuario</label>
                {{ form.username }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.password1.id_for_label }}">Clave</label>
                {{ form.password1 }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="small mb-1" for="{{ form.password2.id_for_label }}">Confirme su clave</label>
                {{ form.password2 }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'nuevoUs' %}">Crear una cuenta "nuevo"</a> -->
                <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Unete' %}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

O incluso, puedes generar las etiquetas `<label>` automáticamente:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.first_name.label_tag }} 
                {{ form.first_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.last_name.label_tag }} 
                {{ form.last_name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.email.label_tag }} 
                {{ form.email }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.username.label_tag }} 
                {{ form.username }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.password1.label_tag }} 
                {{ form.password1 }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.password2.label_tag }} 
                {{ form.password2 }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="{% url 'nuevoUs' %}">Crear una cuenta "nuevo"</a> -->
                <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Unete' %}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Esto solucionaría el problema.

Comment: si también ocupe eso `reverse_lazy` pero igual no me funciona siempre va al **home**, sin crear el usuario claro

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, con la solución, échale un vistaso.

Comment: si tambien me di cuenta de eso pero tampoco incluso poniendo `name` en los input no toma el valor, y pues no actualice incluso puse `required="True"` pero nada

Comment: Eso debería solucionar tu problema. El modelo `AuthUser` es el modelo que utilizas para login, registros, recuperar email, etc? Si es así, modificaste la constante `AUTH_USER_MODEL` en tu archivo `settings.py`?

Comment: si use ese modelo recuperar clave, pero no modifique nada importo el modelo `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` para la FK de las actividades del usuario, en **settings.py** agregre `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` y `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL` y lo usual, temple, `EMAIL_HOST`... y el resto para recuperar clave

Comment: ya funciono mm m suele pasar ya m acostumbre **GRACIAS** quiza sabes [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349979/accessing-modelform-queryset-object-field-in-template)

Comment: OK un gusto ayudarte. Respecto al enlace no entiendo que quieres decir xD

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109404/discussion-between-cristian-and-julio-cesar).